# C++: Is there anything wrong with putting my code into a try-block which runs in an endless loop?

Tags: c++, exception

Consider this example: I have some code that processes user input 24/7. It only stops if the programmer tells it to or if an exception is thrown and the application crashes. Would there be anything wrong with doing the following to effectively restart the code in case of a crash:

```
#include <iostream>

void myEndlessFunction(){
//This function never returns until user intervention or an exception is thrown
//...
}

int main(){

  while(true){
    try{
      myEndlessFunction();
    }
    catch(...){
      //Do some logging
    }
  }

}
```

Would this be a good alternative to having some external service that keeps this application running?

Comment: What if the condition is bad enough so that the only choice is to terminate the program?

Comment: I'd say that could be handled in the catch-block. E.g. terminate the program if a certain exception is thrown a certain number of times.